# How to use bootstrap login form to authenticate django users

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-authentication

I'm building my very first Django web application and there's one issue that I can't seem to find a solution for.

My homepage (index.html) is bootstrap-based and it displays some text together with a bootstrap log in form.

What is the correct way to allow Django authentication from that bootstrap login form?

I've tried solutions based on suggestions found here and there on the internet, but I keep getting errors.

Here's my code:

Inside index.html

```
<div class="inner cover">
  <h1 class="cover-heading">Admin Interface</h1>
  <p class="lead">Welcome to your dedicated Admin Interface.<br>Log in to access your dashboard and control panel.</p>
  <form class="form-signin">
    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
      </label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Inside myapp/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from user import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Inside my main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('user.urls')),

]
```

I tried adding form method="post" action="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %} but it does not work.

Do you have any idea on how I should proceed?

Thank you very much in advance.

Giulia

Comment: I don't think you problem has to do with bootstrap since it doesn't touch your server, if you need to login you can create a login view in which you'll log the users when the informations in the form are correct. Then you could use `{% url 'name_of_your_view' %}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the url on urls.py.

```
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('user.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_view.login, name="login"),

]
```

then route it on action

```
<form method='POST' action = '{% url 'login' %}' class="form-signin">
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply, I've tried your solution but I get the error name 'auth-view' is not defined. How can I define it?

Comment: you write `auth-view` instead of `auth_view` . 
`from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view`

Comment: also see the 4th line of url

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo while commenting here, on the actual code it was okay. I've added from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_view also to myapp/urls.py and now it works! Previously I had added it only to my main urls.py. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can also use **LoginView** as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
]
```